# "trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/cvlc', which is also in package vlc-nox 2.2.1-5+b1"

Tags: dpkg

I had a KL2016 laying around and installed it on virtualbox, installed, then the problems started after

```
apt-get install && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is the error I get

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  vlc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vlc-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 157 kB of archives.
After this operation, 382 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.xxxx.fr/kali/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 vlc-bin amd64 2.2.6-2 [157 kB]
Fetched 157 kB in 0s (167 kB/s) 
(Reading database ... 340385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../vlc-bin_2.2.6-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-bin (2.2.6-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-bin_2.2.6-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/cvlc', which is also in package vlc-nox 2.2.1-5+b1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-bin_2.2.6-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue with the same scenario.

I had to purge the package mentioned, in this case: vlc-nox.

```
sudo dpkg -P vlc-nox
```

And then run install again.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Should work after that.

Comment: I recommend to purge any packages that might be causing trouble. In my case was vlc-nox and red5-server